# Частица НЕ со словом "ясно"?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Правильно ли написать НЕЯСНО слитно в выражении "С йогой пока ничего неясно..."? Заранее СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 4):

Правило звучит так: частица НЕ пишется раздельно, если слову с этой частицей предшествует отрицательное местоимение или отрицательное наречие. В данном предложении перед словом с частицей НЕ (не ясно) стоит отрицательное местоимение НИЧЕГО, поэтому частица НЕ пишется раздельно

Answer (score 0):

Здесь - раздельно.
В сочетании с частицей "НИ" и местоимениями "никто", "ничто", "никогда" и т.д. не - раздельно.